# nginx and codeigniter (telling a server to put all traffic through index.php?)

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, nginx

Basically, the htaccess I use with apache says something like "if the requested file or directory does not exist, route the request through index.php"

How exactly can I do this with nginx?

That way, if a stylesheet is requested, it's served. But if the url isn't to a file on disk, then it should run the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this, is to ignore certain extensions...

The configuration bellow runs everything except gif/jpg etc... through modify.php

```
    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|pdf)$ {
              root   /home/site/public_html;
            expires 365d;

    }

    location / {
        root   /home/site/public_html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^/(.*) /modify.php?file=$1;
            expires 5m;
    }
```

You can also test for the existance of a file with -f (though I prefer to avoid the extra stat call).  The example bellow passes requests for missing files through to a proxy:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
  break;
  proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1;
}
```